# VS Code opened via VS Developer Command Prompt not recognizing 'cl'

Tags: visual-studio-code, cl

As the title says, VS Code is not recognizing `cl` compiler although opened via `Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt`:
[image: VS Developer Command Prompt]

VS Code terminal:
[image]

I have tried using VS Code external terminal with 
`%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`
which did not work.
Setting the `comspec` manualy in the terminal did solve the issue for the terminal instance:
[image]

But the `C++` extension is still complaining about `cl.exe`:
`cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.`

I have never used VS Code for C++ before and I don't use windows for development at all so go easy on me.

**What could be the reason for the issue and how it can be solved?**

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt must be elevated(run as Administrator) in order to correctly open VS Code with the needed permissions.

Running Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt as Admin solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me is to go directly in the setting for C++ extension and find compiler path setting, and manually set it to cl.exe path on your computer.